# Создание экземпляров класса из цикла (Swift)

Tags: массивы, swift, swift4, синтаксис

Есть два массива (names и surnames), 5 элементов в каждом.
Есть пустой массив (employees), тип String.
Есть класс Employee с тремя свойствами (Name, Surname,  Salary)

Как можно через цикл в массив employees создать десять объектов класса Employee, чтобы свойства name и surname брались случайно из массивов names и surnames и не повторялись?.. 
Так же для каждого экземпляра класса нужно создать случайное значение salary в диапазоне от 10 до 1000?...

Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, что (name, surname) должно быть уникальным. Код для Xcode playground. В таком случае тебе нужно самому следить за максимальным количеством уникальных вариантов.

```
class Employee {
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var salary: Int

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String, salary: Int) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.salary = salary
  }
}

struct Tupple<T:Hashable,U:Hashable> : Hashable {
  static func == (lhs: Tupple<T, U>, rhs: Tupple<T, U>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.values == rhs.values
  }

  let values : (T, U)

  var hashValue : Int {
    get {
      let (a,b) = values
      return a.hashValue &* 31 &+ b.hashValue
    }
  }
}

let names = ["Dave", "Bob", "John", "Stan", "Bill"]
let surnames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Miller"]
var employees = [Employee]()
var hashes = [Int]()

while hashes.count < 10 {
  let randomfirstName = names.randomElement()
  let randomLastName = surnames.randomElement()
  let salary = Int.random(in: 10...1000)

  let uniqueID = Tupple(values: (randomfirstName, randomLastName))
  if !hashes.contains(uniqueID.hashValue) {
    hashes.append(uniqueID.hashValue)
    let employee = Employee(firstName: randomfirstName!, lastName: randomLastName!, salary: salary)
    employees.append(employee)
  }
}

for employee in employees {
  print("\(employee.firstName) \(employee.lastName) \(employee.salary)")
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо на счет проверки на уникальность - её я сделать сам не смог :)

Comment: @Roraks Если ответ вам помог, поставьте "Ответ полезен" и/или "Отметить как ответ", вы этим мотивируете участников давать ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам и сделал как-то так (после того как создали класс с 3мя свойствами):

```
var employees = [Employee]()

for _ in 1...10 {
let randomName = names.randomElement()!             // Берём имя из массива
let randomSurname = surnames.randomElement()!       // Берём фамилию из массива
let randomSalary = Int.random(in: 1000...2000)      // Генерируем зарплату
let newEmployee = Employee(name: randomName, surname: randomSurname, salary: randomSalary) // Создаём экземпляры класса

//print("Сотрудник \(newEmployee.name) \(newEmployee.surname) - зарплата $\(newEmployee.salary)")  // Проверяем создание экземпляра класса

employees.append(newEmployee)  // Добавляем экземпляр класса в массив
}
```